# Sending files to a discord forum

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I'm trying to send every file one at a time to a discord forum but nothing is working, it's meant to make a new discord forum then within the title of the forum goes the csv file name then within the description puts in the file it self. I've managed the bot to upload the files to a normal channel but when it comes to a forum it cannot find the files or says that the directory doesn't exist

```
const { Client, Discord, GatewayIntentBits, ForumChannel, Attachment,  } = require('discord.js');
const { buffer } = require('stream/consumers');
const fs = require('fs').promises;

const client = new Client({
  intents: [
    GatewayIntentBits.Guilds,
    GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessages,
    GatewayIntentBits.MessageContent,
    GatewayIntentBits.GuildMembers,
    GatewayIntentBits.GuildModeration,
    GatewayIntentBits.GuildMembers,
    GatewayIntentBits.AutoModerationConfiguration,
    //Discord.GatewayIntentBits.GuildForumMessage
  ]
})
//const thread = '1099921205324173332'; // Replace with your channel ID

client.on('ready', () => {
  console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}!`);
});

client.on('messageCreate', async message => {
  // Check if the message author is the bot
  if (message.author.bot) return;

  // Check if the message contains the !upload command
  if (message.content.startsWith('!upload')) {
    // Get the directory path from the message content
    const dirPath = message.content.split(' ')[1];
    thread = "1099921205324173332"
    // Check if the directory exists
    const fs = require('fs');
    if (fs.existsSync(dirPath) && fs.lstatSync(dirPath).isDirectory()) {
      // Read all the files in the directory
      const fileNames = fs.readdirSync(dirPath);

      // Loop through each file and upload it to the channel
      for (const fileName of fileNames) {
        const filePath = `${dirPath}/${fileName}`;
        const buffer = fs.readFileSync(filePath);
        GuildForumMessageRequired = 'GuildForumMessageRequired'
        {
      const threadChannel = message.guild.channels.cache.find(channel => channel.name === 'test');      
      threadChannel.threads.create({
        name: fileName.name,
        autoArchiveDuration: 60,
        type: 'GUILD_PUBLIC_THREAD',
        message: {
          content: `New thread created with file:` ,//"${fileName.name.replace('/[^a-zA-Z ]/g, ""')}!`,
          files: [ fileName]
          }
      });
      }
        console.log(`Uploaded ${fileName} to ${message.channel.name}`);
      }
    }
     else 
     {
      // If the directory doesn't exist, send an error message
      message.reply('The specified directory does not exist.');
    }
  console.log(`Created thread: ${thread.name}`);
  }
});

client.login('token here');
```

What is expected of the bot should be new discord forum, title as the file name then file in description but the actual output is within this image, it can find the files but cannot upload them to the forum thread

[image]

Comment: Seems like `readDirectory()` requires a `cb` (callback) argument, and none was given.